# How can I automatically re-open a program if it terminates / closes / crashes?

Tags: windows, java

I've created a Java JAR program that needs to be running all the time in the computer. If the program is closed (either because the user closed it or because it crashed), I need to reopen the program.

I already managed to autostart it whenever I log in the computer, but how can I keep it alive?

I'm not sure whether this should be a programming question or not. After all, auto-starting programs is not a programming question, so I figured that making them persistent could be a similar case.

Comment: To be sure here, what is the command used to start-up this java jar program now? what is your method of starting it at log-in? the worlds simplest method would be to use "Start /Wait" methods of running it , and just repeat that in a batch or have an infinite loop. It would help to know first though how your already doing this and with what exact command structure.  Are you positive that when it crashes the executable fully terminates?

Comment: @Psycogeek it's just a .bat file in the startup folder as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5953583/555690

Answer (score 3):

Put this into a `.bat`/`.cmd` file. Adjust the `java` invocation to your needs. Start the cmd file from autostart.
Make sure to use `java`, not `javaw`, since you want to wait until it's finished before starting it the next time.

```
:start
"C:\Program Files\java\bin\java" -jar my.jar
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several program you can use for this. One is called Control Running Programs (CRP). This is a very good tool to use when having this problem.

Here's a link for that............

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/keep-application-running-by-automatically-rerun-when-closed/

Hope this answers your question, if not let me know.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, for example how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: CRP won't open/work on Windows 10. Epic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a question over at stack overflow about how to turn a .bat file into a service:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294293

The top answer to that question is to use nssm (http://nssm.cc/). When your bat file is made into a service it will automatically restart when it closes.

Usage for your purpose would be something like the following within an administrator prompt:

```
nssm install yourservicename yourbatfile.bat
nssm start servicename
nssm stop servicename
```